# How to write a query for sales by month of individual items

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, chart.js

I have a mysql table of past car reservations which includes the following columns:

Type of Vehicle (r_vehicle) - 
Month of the reservation (r_month)

I basically need to get back data like this:

Limo had 3 sales in Jan, 2 in Feb, etc.
Sedan had 5 sales in Jan, 3 in Feb, etc.

I am integrating Charts.JS which asks for the data in this way:

```
<script>
    var MONTHS = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Limo",
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
                borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
                data: [
                    LOOP OVER SALES PER MONTH FOR LIMO
                ],
                fill: false,
            }, {
                label: "Sedan",
                fill: false,
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                data: [
                   LOOP OVER SALES PER MONTH FOR SEDAN
                ],
            }]
        }
```

How can I write the query and then iterate over it in a way that Charts.js will be happy with?
FYI: I am using Coldfusion as server-side code.
Thanks for any guidance!!!

Comment: Regarless of how you write your query, you will still have to iterate over it in javascript and generate different `data` arrays for each vehicle type.  Is that have you are having trouble with?  Processing your data in javascript to prepare it for using in your chart?

Comment: Hi JordanWillis, yes that's also part of my problem.  User88748's code is returning things the way I think they need to be.  But I do indeed need to know how to loop over that data the way Charts.js wants.

Comment: Take a shot at doing it yourself and ask another question with your code in case you run into trouble.  I would just iterate over your query results using `.forEach` and `.push` values into each car type array within some `if/else` blocks.

Comment: Excellent, will do.  Thank you both for the help!

Comment: Side note, if the table also contains a year, do not forget to account for that in your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would easily get this data using GROUP BY of r_vehicle and r_month

```
SELECT r_vehicle, r_month, COUNT (*)
FROM reservations
GROUP BY r_vehicle, r_month
ORDER BY r_vehicle, r_month;
```

In case you would have missing values in the reservations table where you are missing few month values, you would need to create a temp table with all month values and do a LEFT JOIN of this table with reservations table.

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot for this, it does seem to be doing the query part correctly (I did have to remove the whitespace between the word COUNT and the (*), by the way).  Just need to figure out the loop part now and I'm doing good!  Cheers!

Comment: glad that it works. please upvote the answers if it solves your problems.

Comment: It solves the first part (the 2nd part is iterating over that query the way Chart.js wants it).  How should I handle this on StackOverflow?  Do I upvote each response that helps?  Sorry, I'm not a pro here yet!!

Comment: Just upvoted it but it doesn't show until i have 1 more reputation point!!!!   Thank you a lot for the help, User88748!